# Function call to Gift message capturing, no message entered by the customer: how to handle simple scenario?

Tags: event-observer

Good Evening: The event being used here is sales_order_place_after. I want to collect message our customer enter when placing the order. It is noticeable that this event doesn't handle when customer doesn't want t to leave a gift message. In this scenario, this event does nothing but ends up in a mess. Please advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@PKTG, I seem to have had a similar issue. If you have followed the standard approach to retrieve the gift message, adding the following piece of code snippet would most likely help fix the issue. Let me know in case of any questions.

```
$gift_object  = $this->_orderGiftRepo->get($order->getId());
$gift_message = $gift_object->getMessage();
} catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
// Do nothing. No gift message specified. Valid scenario.
} catch (\Exception $e) {
$this->_logger->debug("Empty Gift Message for this order: " . $e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Approach is same. let me check this resolution. okay?

Comment: Wonderful..It is saving much time to me. and for other future coders also. great answer.